# scope of declaration of some members in java

Tags: java

what are the scope of static and instant method, and static or instance variable in java? if they are in the same class or another class.

Comment: Pasting questions to stackoverflow is not going to give you answers. Have you tried anything yourself or do you want us to do all the work? -- "With some examples please." - No.

Comment: @f1sh searching for something which is not there is harder. ;)

Comment: I'm not pasting this and thanks for this reply

Comment: Your teacher gave you this question so you would think. Not so you could copy an answer from the WWW.

Comment: first I have noooo teacher that is self learning programming java from some sources really.I'm beginning in this okey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer your question using an example. Hope it will give you better clarity of the same.

***StaticExample.java***

```
    public class StaticExample {

    public static int Static_var= 0 ; 
    public int instance_var = 0 ;

    public static void changeValStatic(){

        Static_var ++; // Accessing static variable from static method.

        //  instance_var++;  --> Error because it is not possible to access instance variables in static methods

        changeVal2Static(); // Calling static method of the same class.

        //  display();     --> Error because it  is not possible to access non static (instance) methods in static methods.
    }

    public static void changeVal2Static(){

        System.out.println("Call to second static method");

    }

    public void changeValInstance(){

        Static_var ++; // Access to static variable from instance method

        instance_var++; // Access to instance variable from instance method
    }

    public void display(){
        //Printing instance and static variable
        System.out.println("Instance variable :- " + this.instance_var);
        System.out.println("Static variable :- " + Static_var );
    }
}
```

***StaticExampleTest.java***

```
public class StaticExampleTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StaticExample se = new StaticExample();// Create an instance of StaticExample class

            se.changeValInstance(); //call the instance method using "se" instance of StaticExample class

            //se.changeValStatic(); Not error but Invalid because Static methods are class methods , should be called using class name

            StaticExample.changeValStatic(); // Valid Call to static method 

            se.display(); //Call to instance method.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> what are the scope of static and instant method, and static or instant field in java?

The scope of a `static` member is the class it is in.

There nothing which "instant" in a computer, everything takes time.

An *instance* variable also has the scope of the class. Note: you can only access an instance variable on a instance.

> Is static method can call only static members in the same class?

A static method can call any method static or otherwise.  If it calls a instance method it must provide the *instance* it is calling that method on.

Note: an instance method can only call an instance method on a method also. The difference is; if you don't specify an instance Java assumes you what to use `this` but for a `static` method there is no `this` to use.

Comment: @user3010791 What do you mean by an instant variable? Do you mean an *instance* variable?

Comment: sorry instance variable

Comment: yes instance variable

Answer (score 1):

*Static methods, variables, and initialization code have these characteristics.*

```
They’re associated with a class.
They’re initialized only when a class is loaded.
```

*Instance methods, member variables have these characteristics.*

```
They’re associated with a particular object.
They’re created with every object instantiated from the class in which they’re declared.
```